# Empty istanbul (nyc) report while coverage files are filled properly with Selenium

Tags: selenium, code-coverage, istanbul

The web app is written in python + typescript and uses Selenium for the font-end tests.
I've tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747010/javascript-code-coverage-using-selenium-istanbul#) to setup the test coverage analysis. The simplified pipeline is:

1. After TS --> JS conversion the code is instrumented with nyc `nyc instrument ./dist/js_cov/ ./dist/js/ --embed-source true`
2. Selenium runs some tests and stores the output in the .nyc_output folder. The files are generated correctly with coverage info inside e.g.

```
{"path/vars.bundle.js":{"path":"path/vars.bundle.js""statementMap":{"0":{"start":{"line":1,"column":9},"end":{"line":550,"column":1}},...
```

I've also checked that in the browser console `window.__coverage__` looks well with the list of files and coverage results.

3. I expect `nyc report --cwd .` to show the coverage result, but the report is always empty. Neither files nor coverage results are shown.

```
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

`nyc merge` works fine and create a general coverage file for all the tests, bu the report is still empty

What could be the problem that causes an empty report?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something very similar trying to get coverage using playwright on our application. The `nyc report --cwd .` was key to getting it to output correctly. Where ever you run that from you should have the `.nyc_output` folder directly under it. While that worked I still had bad paths when trying to lookup individual files and had to override `node_modules/istanbul-lib-report/lib/context.js` directly and rewrite the `defaultSourceLookup` function to correct the path.